# OpenLayers3: How to remove or delete point?

Tags: openlayers-3

In my OpenLayers3 map, I can easily create points or linestrings.
When I modify linestrings, I can set up the Modify interaction to be able to delete a vertex on a shift-click.  I then get a callback on the linestring feature on('change') event.

For points, I get no such callback and in fact the shift-click does not delete the point.

I was referencing this example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=modify

Now that I think about it, what I really might want to do is have a select interaction and when the user selects a point with a shift-click, that point would be deleted.

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Thanks

--
I updated my application to have a selection handler for deletion; Now I'm having a problem where the selection is happening on a click, even though I specify it should select on a shift-click.

```
this.stationDeleter = new ol.interaction.Select({
                        layers: [this.stationsLayer],
                        // for debugging
                        style: new ol.style.Style({
                            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                              radius: 12,
                              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                              })
                            })
                          }),
                        addCondition: function(event) {
                            return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event)
                            && ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
                          }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between deleting a vertex of a feature and deleting the whole geometry. To delete the whole geometry it's a good idea to use a `Select` interaction. Like in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/modify-features.html

If there is a feature selected, you could show a control with a button "Remove selected feature".

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, adding a select interaction; when features are added to that select interaction I delete 'em.